# Is there a word that means 'adapted for land speed' specifically?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to know if there is a word to refer to an animal being adapted to move fast. I have found the word 'cursorial', but that specifically refers to being adapted to run fast, and so wouldn't apply to animals that can't run

Comment: What precise context do you want to use this in? A word that often means adapted to move fast is "fast".

Comment: Which animal are you thinking of that is adapted to move fast on land but does not run?  A snake??  Fastest snake is only 10-12 mph.

Comment: @Jim Kangaroos can go more than 40 mph.

Comment: @Acccumulation - Ahh.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

“Adapted for land speed” has two concepts, adaptation and speed. The first includes an implicit assumption, for biological organisms, of Darwinian evolution. There are many traits involved in selection, speed being only one.

According to this Wikipedia article, speed for different organisms is measured in body lengths per unit of time. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastest_animals